# How to combine two lists into tuple list (like Cartesian Products) in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose `list1 = [1, 2, 3]` and `list2 = ["a", "b"]`

I want to combine them such that I get a tuple list like so:

`list3 = [(1, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "a"), (3, "b")]`

Is there any way to do this concisely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it fairly easily with Scala's `for ... yield` expression.

```
for {
  x <- list1
  y <- list2
} yield {
  (x, y)
}
```

This desugars to `flatMap` and `map` calls, so it's equivalent to

```
list1.flatMap { x => list2.map { y => (x, y) } }
```

If you're using **Scalaz**, then the Cartesian product is just an application of the [`Applicative`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.scalaz/scalaz_2.13/7.4.0-M3/scalaz/Applicative.html) instance for lists. With appropriate Scalaz imports, this will suffice

```
^(list1, list2) { (_, _) }
```

[**cats**](https://typelevel.org/cats/) has similar functionality with different syntax:

```
import cats.syntax.all._
(list1, list2).tupled
```